# Architecture choice for variable input dimension sizes

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, training, image

So, I am doing this project where I have lets say a bunch of points. Each of those points can have a different number of RGB values. So lets say point 1 might have 30 RGB values, point 2 might have 500 rgb values. The idea is I want to decide something based on the variances those RGB values have across them. The idea has more than this to it, however I wanted to state it here in simple terms. I am kind of at a loss as to how I would fit this varying size of data as input and what architecture should I be approaching towards. Any clue or pointer would help.

Comment: When you say points, do you mean vectors? Matrices? Images?

Comment: By points I mean a single (x,y,z) of a bunch of (x,y,z) of the point cloud. Say, 13.5, 14.5, 20 is a single point. It might have 30 RGB values depending on how it looked in the various cameras.